# Is $f''(x)=0$ sufficient for inflection point?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm a bit confused about $n$th derivative test.Is $f''(x)=0$ at a point sufficient to prove it is inflection point or not ?Or we need to check further if any higher odd derivative is $0$?

And when is it sufficient to conclude that if at a point of a function $f''(x)=0$ it is an inflection point ?

Assume the derivative is 0 that that point.

Comment: No. It is a necessary condition.

Comment: example $x\longmapsto x^4$.

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition)?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, you meant it is not sufficient. It is necessary condition. If $f''(x_0) \ne 0$ then $x_0$ is not an inflection point.

Comment: @Galc127 Umm...I said it is a necessary condition....

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $x_0$ is an inflection point of $f(x)$ if the concavity of $f(x)$ switches at this point. We know that $f(x)$ is concave up at $x$ if $f''(x) > 0$ and it is concave down at $x$ if $f''(x) < 0$. Therefore $x_0$ is an inflection point of $f(x)$ exactly when the sign of $f''(x)$ changes at $x_0$.

For instance, if $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x<x_0$, $f''(x_0) = 0$, and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x>x_0$, then $x_0$ is an inflection point. More generally, you only need to check that $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x$ which are less than but close to $x_0$, i.e. for all $x$ in the interval $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0)$ for some small positive number $\epsilon$. You would similarly need to check that $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x$ greater than, but close to $x_0$. Or of course, you can reverse the signs, so that $f''(x)$ changes from positive to negative. You do need to check that the sign changes though, in any event.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not sufficient, it's only necessary. For $f$ to have a inflexion point at $x$, the sign of $f''(x)$ must change at the point $x$.